# How to extend lists without list.extend method and without '+' operator

Tags: python, function, methods, operator-keyword, extend

I am tring to do an extending function, one that will work as list.extend method, but i don't want it to contain list.extend method or the '+' operator, and in addition I need to extend 'x' and not to 'y' (you will see).

first of all, this is x and y:

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried this: 
`x = y, x`
But it is giving me this result: `([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`, and I ran out of ideas...

The thing that I want to do (without extend method and '+' operator) will look like this:

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3]
extending_func(x, y)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to do a function like "extending_func" but I dont succes to bring it all to one list, and i dont know if i need to chage the type of list to somthing else to do it, or that I need just a simple idea to solve it. I tried also to use list.append, but it is giving me the next result (just to try the idea, but as i wrote i need to extend x and not y):

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3]
y.append(x)
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: use `append` in a loop.

Comment: I learn in an internet course, and I didn't get to this lesson (I know how to program, but I should not use loops yet...)

Comment: the answer with slicing is the best

Comment: so you cannot use `extend` or `+=` just because?

Comment: it is a bonus task in my course and i didnt knew how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `y` to `x` using list slicing:

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3]
x[:0] = y
print(x)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Just note that the order you append the lists in is very important in this case; `y = [1, 2, 3]` is being added in front (at index 0) of `x = [4, 5, 6]` (see [this tweak by Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225343/how-to-extend-lists-without-list-extend-method-and-without-operator/49225400#49225400) for a better method)

Answer (score 2):

Xay answer is smart with the slicing, but it inserts the data in front.

A little tweak:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
def extending_func(x, y):
   x[len(x):] = y

extending_func(x,y)
print(x)
```

prints:

```
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```