# Appending a list to a class object (python)

Tags: python, list, class, object, arraylist

Unable to execute following code with the below class:

Expected result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 90, 25] Given result = <**main**.ArrayList object at 0x7f9f1439acd0>

How can I stop this from happening? Without built in extend()

Any help appreciated

```
class ArrayList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inArray = []
        self.count = 0

    def appendAll(self, e):
        newArray = [0 for i in range(len(self.inArray)+1)]
        for i in range(len(self.inArray)):
            newArray[i] = self.inArray[i]
            newArray[len(self.inArray)] = e
            self.inArray = newArray

ls = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ls = ArrayList()
ls.appendAll([90, 25])
print(ls)
```

Comment: You meant to `print(ls.inArray)`... Or add a `__str__(self):`method that returns `str(self.inArray)` if you want to use `print(ls)`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Python by default returns the reference to the user-defined class object, and not it's data members.

Here's what I think you want to implement...

```
class ArrayList:
    def __init__(self, inArray: list = []):
        self.inArray = inArray
        self.count : int = 0

    def appendAll(self, newArray: list):
        self.inArray.extend(newArray)   # extend() can add multiple values at a time
    
    def __str__(self):                  # __str__ is a magic/dunder method (Special function reserved in Python which gets activated when you try to print an object of it's class)
        return str(self.inArray)


if __name__=='__main__':
    ls = ArrayList([1, 2, 3, 4])    # Initialize ArrayList object with default value
    ls.appendAll([90, 25])          # Add more values
    print(ls)
```

I've corrected your code, and for you have added concepts called:
1 [Type-Hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)
2. '**main**' Function

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve, but without extend() hence why the loop in appendAll

Comment: What you tried to do in appendAll comes already implemented in python as extend() method

Comment: I understand, but I am working on making my own extend function (so far I have created my own append function that extends by one element but not multiple, and have created remove, get functions, etc.

Comment: this is what I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225343/how-to-extend-lists-without-list-extend-method-and-without-operator @HIMANSHUPANDEY